# REST Get items not in collection

Tags: rest, search

**Introduction**

Let's say I have a rest service which returns items:

```
GET /items
GET /items/7    
POST /items
etc.
```

We also  have groups of items:

```
GET /groups
GET /groups/16
POST /groups
etc.
```

And we can then get the items in a specific group:

```
/items?groupid=16
```

This is all pretty straight forward.

**Question**

Now that we have a way to get items in a specific group, should we also supply a way to get items that are NOT in a specific group? Why? Because if a client wants to add items to a group, it has to know which items aren't added yet.

I see two options:

1. We supply some way to query the data
2. Don't do anything, let the client handle it.

*Ad 1.*

We can supply a way to query/search the data like this:

```
/items?groupid=!16
or
/items?q=groupid<>16
```

I have the feeling this leads to a never ending stream of feature requests for search queries.

*Ad 2.*

The client can first get all items. Next the client can get all items in group 16. Doing a diff on these two collections gives the items not in group 16.

This way the client has to do a little more coding, and work with collections, keep them in memory etc. On the other hand it doesn't need to learn a specific query syntax.

*Are there any best practicies on this topic?*

Comment: Do you see any value for your customers to look for something that doesn't match a certain value? If so, you can totally add the option and customers will be happy to deal with the query syntax. In my experience people usually look for something e.g. `groupId=XX`, I've never being asked to support the option where something is not equal to some value.

Comment: A client want to add items to a group. For this the client has to know which items don't belong to that group yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd use a different URL to get the items in a group:

```
GET /groups/16/items
```

This would return the collection resource of all items that are in group 16. To **add** an item to a group,

```
POST /groups/16/items
```

could be used.

Adding an item to a group will have the same result, regardless of the item already being in the group or not. In both cases the client only cares about the result: he wants the item to be in the group. If it already was, fine, if not, it is now.

So I don't see any usecase for getting items that are not in a group.

Comment: Usecase: picture a screen with on the left side the items in the group, and on the right side the items you can choose to add to the group. If all items are in the group, I want the list of items to choose from, to be empty.

Comment: I would handle that client-side. It would require two REST calls though.

Comment: Your usecase can easily be handled by the client: 1) get *all* items, 2) get the items in the group, 3) calculate the different.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps allowing the client to POST the new item to the desired group could be the way to go.

During the validation you would need anyway, you could either accept the not-pre-existing item or reject it because it is already there.

---

Building on the URLs of @Tichodroma, you could perhaps have:

GET /groups/16/non-items